# get width for a div in jquery , whose width is auto

Tags: jquery, css

I want to get the width of a div **whose width is set as auto**

I tried :

```
$(".my_class").outerWidth(true);

$(".my_class").width();
```

Both shows me 0 width , I don't know why. Any other alternative ?

Comment: Both of those should work, so long as the `div` element does have content in it to give it a width. Can you edit your question to include the CSS and HTML, or better yet set up a http://jsfiddle.net example.

Comment: i tried making a jsfiddle ,, but there these codes work fine

Comment: Then the issue is not with retrieving the width, but elsewhere in your code. Unless you can give us a more complete example of your code, we cannot help you.

Comment: It's working here. http://jsfiddle.net/NkQXa/253/ There may any different issue. Can you show full code Or live link also

Comment: Are you calling your JS after the element renders?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it's possible for the moment. At least not in any other browser than IE. IE implements element.currentStyle which represents styles at they were written in the CSS file. On the other hand, the rest of the browsers implement window.getComputedStyle which returns the computed values of those styles. That's what you receive there, a numeric value instead of auto.

The only way around it would be to parse CSS declarations from document.styleSheets.

```
References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231(VS.85).aspx
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM:window.getComputedStyle
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/computed_value
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added a HTML DOM method (alternative method)  to  identify the width of an element.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName(".my_class"); //Fetching the div element
alert(x[0].style.width); //Fetching the width of the selected div element.
```

I have assumed that there is only 1 div with "*my_class*" as its class name. If many are there, certain processing has to be done on the retrieved list to identify the particular element.

This also may not work for you and as a best practice, root cause of the issue shall be identified.

Answer (score 0):

use [.clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)

`cur_element = document.getElementById('my_div');
console.log('width: ' + cur_element.clientWidth);`